# Display batch operations messages

Tags: 7, batch-operations

I have defined a batch, everything works ok, but I want to understand how the messages are displayed. So I have this batch:

```
$batch = array(
  'title' => t('Generate reports'),
  'operations' => array(
    array('create_report_callback', array($time_min, $time_max)),
  ),
  'init_message' => t('Starting report generation...'),
  'progress_message' => t('Generating report. Operation @current out of @total.'),
  'error_message' => t('Error detected. Please try again!'),
  'finished' => 'create_report_finished',
);
```

What I want to know is how to change the `progress_message` to something else than `Operation @current out of @total`. I don't know where the `@current` and `@total` come from

Thank you.

Comment: You can just change it to whatever you like, those are placeholders the batch processor will inject automatically if necessary. They aren't mandatory, just available

Comment: Ok, clear enough. But is it possible to have a dynamic message, with custom placeholders? Basically to generate the message inside the batch process function.

Comment: The docs suggest it's not possible without altering core: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/batch_set/7 (search for "@current" in that page)

Answer (score 0):

The placeholders `@current`, `@total`, etc are described in the file `includes/form.inc` in the description of the `batch_set()` function.

> - progress_message: Message displayed while processing the batch.
>     Available placeholders are @current, @remaining, @total,
>     @percentage, @estimate and @elapsed. Defaults to t('Completed
>     @current of @total.').

---

You can add custom placeholders by using the t() function like this:

```
$my_custom_variable = 'contents of my custom variable';

$batch = array(
  'title' => t('Generate reports'),
  'operations' => array(
    array('create_report_callback', array($time_min, $time_max)),
  ),
  'init_message' => t('Starting report generation...'),
  'progress_message' => t('Generating @my_custom_placeholder report. Operation @current out of @total.', 
     array(
       '@my_custom_placeholder' => $my_custom_variable,
     )
  ),
  'error_message' => t('Error detected. Please try again!'),
  'finished' => 'create_report_finished',
);
```